# jQuery Drag - bind a div to draggable div

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag

I just posted a question but I think I should reword it into something more general. Basically, I have an element that you can move around and resize using jQuery. Using CSS, I attached another div to this, to the right of it. When you first load the page, it's right where it's supposed to be. However, when I start to drag or resize the draggable div, the one that's originally attached to it stays where it is.

**Is there any way to bind this div to the other one, so that it moves with it?** Preferrably, without putting it in a container, as that complicates more things considering the nature of my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this without using a container, but you don't need both elements in a container; you just need the "follower" to be a child of the draggable div.

Make sure the "follower" div is a child of the draggable div in your markup:

```
<div class="draggable">
    <p>I'm draggable...</p>
    <div class="follower">I follow</div>
</div>
```

In your CSS, set position on the outer div, but don't specify any offsets:

```
.draggable { position: relative; }
```

Then, position the inner div, and give it offsets from the parent. You can position the inner as absolute or relative -- in both cases, it will position itself relative to the nearest container that has position, in this case the parent draggable:

```
.follower { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    right: 20px;
    etc...
}
```

Comment: Alright. Giving it a try. However, the inner element, that's supposed to be the tag part itself that you drag? I think it has to be position absolute for it to work, but I could be wrong.

Comment: This is working great, but I'm still running into one problem. When I resize, the right part doesn't go with it. If you want, take a look yourself: http://www.ewsprojects.com/~lyons/new.php. Click "Tag this Picture"

Comment: No the inner element I put in the example is the div to the right that you want to move when the outer div is moved. If you need a drag handle on the outer div, I'd create that as a separate element inside the draggable: 
<div class="draggable">
    <div class="drag-handle">drag me!</div>
    some more content in the draggable...
    <div class="follower">
        I follow, and via CSS appear outside 
        and to the right of my parent
    </div>
</div>

Comment: @Mark, re the failure to resize: change the position on the follower div from absolute to relative. You'll have to tweak the left value to compensate, but now as you resize the draggable, the follower should maintain its offset to the draggable.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I had a feeling it would be a relatively simple CSS fix, I just had no idea haha. Now to negate the opacity on the follower div, which is proving to be equally annoying. If you have a clue, I would appreciate it but don't worry if you don't know.

Comment: @Mark, re opacity, yeah, that's a real problem in the CSS spec -- opacity is inherited in child elements; see this article: http://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/. Unfortnately, his solution negates the one we just discussed -- he removes the parent-child relationship. You may have to make your draggable opaque :(

Comment: Ah, one more way to get the transparency you want: on the draggable, set its background-color to transparent, and set a background-image using a semi-transparent PNG. This way, you get a semi-transparent draggable without using opacity, and so your nested follower can be fully opaque (just leave the opacity property off both elements).